# Delegating to derived class methods via dynamic dispatch

Tags: kotlin

Given the below scenario, where there is some base class that should simply delegate to the derived classes, why is it that the two `apply()` methods in the derived classes are never called?

To demonstrate: in the `main` function, I will call `apply` with two events. In the abstract class, I will `apply` both of these events. There is a generic `apply(Event)` function in the base class, but it should be ignored and via dynamic dispatch go to the individual `apply(EventOne)` and `apply(EventTwo)` methods in the derived class.

I've also tried this with each individual `apply` method returning itself, and the `applyFromHistory` function using a `fold` instead, but got the same result.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val subject = SomeAggregate()

    subject.applyFromHistory(listOf(
        EventOne(123),
        EventTwo("foobar")
    ))
}

sealed class Event
data class EventOne(val id: Int) : Event()
data class EventTwo(val content: String) : Event()

abstract class AggregateRoot(
    private val events : MutableList<Event> = mutableListOf()
) {

    fun applyFromHistory(history: List<Event>) {
        history.forEach { apply(it) }
    }

    fun apply(event: Event) { /* does nothing */ }
}

class SomeAggregate(var id: Int = 0, var content: String = "") : AggregateRoot() {
    fun apply(event: EventOne) {
        id = event.id
    }

    fun apply(event: EventTwo) {
        content = event.content
    }
}
```

I was hoping to get away from:

```
abstract class AggregateRoot(... {

   ...

   abstract fun apply(event: Event)
}

class SomeAggregate(... : AggregateRoot() {

   ...

   override fun apply(event: Event) {
       when(event) {
           is EventOne -> apply(event)
           is EventTwo -> apply(event)
       }
   }

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because dynamic dispatch only applies to `this`, i.e. to method *overrides*.  It doesn't apply to the arguments of a method; method *overloads* are resolved statically, at compile time.

The problem you're facing is traditionally solved with things like the [*visitor pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).  An alternative is performing a lookup based on the runtime type of the argument, which Kotlin allows you to do more elegantly via a [`when` expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression).

Comment: Noted. I had made `apply` abstract and then overridden it in the base class with `when` matching. It's an okay solution, just was hoping to get rid of `when` in the derived classes.